# FFMpegConverter instance is not created from NReco.VideoConverter.dll version 1.1.2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I was trying to use  NReco.VideoConverter.dll assembly in my .NET CORE 2.0 but FFMpegConverter instance is not created. I am getting below exception. Can you look into this and guide me how can I make an instance of FFMpegConverter using NReco.VideoConverter.dll and its version is 1.1.2.

> system.TypeLoadException occurred
>     HResult=0x80131522
>     Message=Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>     Source=Cannot evaluate the exception source

Answer (score 0):

`Uninstall-Package NReco.VideoConverter` from Nuget Package manager Console.
Then:

```
Install-Package NReco.VideoConverter.LT -Version 1.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

As Hossein Shahabi mentioned, for .NET Core application, [NReco.VideoConverter.LT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.VideoConverter.LT) version need to be installed, BUT, be aware of the application type, because as, stated to their [official documentation](https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx), there are some Technical limitations:

VideoConverter invokes FFMpeg in a separate process (with System.Diagnostics.Process) and your project environment/platform should allow that.

This might be **NOT possible** in the following cases:

- partial-trust environments: most shared ASP.NET hostings
- Azure Apps on 'shared' plan. Azure WebJobs / VM-based Azure Apps (plan 'Basic' or higher) can run tasks automated with VideoConverter.
- UWP Apps -- they just don't have System.Diagnostics.Process API used by VideoConverter. You may try Microsoft's FFMpeg interop library for Win10/WinPhone8.1 apps (FFMpeg GPL codecs are not available for non-GPL apps in this case).

VideoConverter works fine with Azure VM instances (Web Role, Worker Role, Azure WebJobs).

**Linux/MacOS + MONO**

LT version (NReco.VideoConverter.LT.dll) allows you to deploy ffmpeg by yourself and use VideoConverter on non-Windows environments like Linux or MacOS.

**.NET Core**

NReco.VideoConverter.LT nuget package includes a build for netstandard2.0 target which is compatible with .NET Core 2.x and 3.x applications.
Don't forget that you should deploy ffmpeg binaries for your target platform(s) (Windows, Linux or OS X) with your .NET Core app.